# I am not able to access View.GONE and View.VIsible in my xml file when using dataBinding

Tags: android, data-binding

I am trying to set the visibility of a textview based on an observable boolean value in my ViewModel. However I am unable to use View.GONE or View.VISIBLE in my xml file.

xml File:
android:visibility="@{viewModel.observableBoolean ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE}"

View Model:

val observableBoolean = ObservableBoolean() // The Class I am using for Boolean

observableBoolean.set(false) // How I am setting it in ViewModel

Comment: I haven't used DataBinding but it seems you are trying to use `observableBoolean` as a `Boolean` which it is not as its a custom class. You can Infact use it as a `var` with Boolean type while keeping `private set`.

Answer (score 0):

I found out my issue. I needed to add the following import to my xml.

```
<data
<import type="android.view.View"/>
<variable type= viewmodel.../>
</data>
```